# keypress to block letter/number on visual basic 2012 OOP method

Tags: vb.net, oop, visual-studio-2012

I want to create a register form using visual studio 2012 and SQL server 2012.

the function i want is:
in the windows form there are two textbox:

- if i type a number on the first textbox  the program will block the number and allow letter
- in the second textbox the program will block letter and allow number

i heard that to do this is to use keypress.

what is the coding for keypress to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ASCII values to do this :

```
If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End If
```

In above example, use can only enter numbers and can use `BackSpace` because this function will allow only these ASCII characters on KeyPress Event.

8 -> BackSpace, 
48-57 -> 0 to 9

Similarly use ASCII characters for characters from a to z ( Both Capital and Small )

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
        If Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```